# In excel, how to make a matrix out of data lists?

Tags: excel, matrix

I want to make a 20 x 20 matrix in excel, given 3 lists of data

For example, the lists are:

[image: dataLists]

And I want to make a matrix like this:

[image: 20_by_20_matrix]

So for example, the first row of the data reads: TYR MET   3.
In the matrix, where the column(green) reads TYR and the row(red) reads MET, I put a 3.

I am making several of these matrices, and it take a lot of time to plug in each value manually. Do you have any ideas for formula, code, or tool that would help make this matrix in excel?

Many thanks!!!

Comment: Look into using pivot tables within your Excel document.

Comment: Just to clarify: By "making the matrix", I already have the template, and I'm looking for a way to read in the data from the lists and plugging them in corresponding cells in the matrix template

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you. Could you possibly go into more detailed instructions with the Pivot Table? I'm not very familiar with them

Comment: Google pivot tables.  Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Okay, I found tutorials on YouTube. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I suggested pivot tables, because the solution you want may be as as simple as just _creating_ a pivot table.  Let Excel do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: A quick formula in H2: `=SUMPRODUCT((A:A = $G2)*(B:B = H$1)*(D:D))` then copy over and down. But I agree if a pivot table will work it would be the best.

Comment: @ScottCraner Many thanks! I got the Pivot Table to work. I'll try your formula as well.